# Android testing - How to click on OpenGL resource on the UI?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm running automated tests on an Android app which I don't have the source code for, but I know the UI is a 2D interface made with OpenGL. The problem is, getting screen dumps through uiautomator, monitor or layout inspector doesn't work like it would with other activities, there are no ids or objects, just a blank screen.

So I'm running input clicks by position to navigate the UI, but it changes often, so that makes the code unreliable. I have tried using gapid, but I don't know if it can help me click on screen elements. Is there any way to analyze the screen and get ids or positions, or anything that will help me automate navigating an OpenGL ui on Android?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL have no information about geometry you draw. It can be image or button. Or you can draw two buttons in one batch.

To solve your problem you have to provide information about controls for your automated tests. You can try to create invisible controls (Button or TextView) on top of your OpenGL scene (ofc for debug configuration only). So you can query positions as usual.